# Triplet round instead of square

Tags: sheet-music, lilypond, tuplet

I'd like to use a round bracket instead the square bracket for the Triplets but I can't find a solution.
Here the exemple with regular square bracket: http://lilybin.com/iqdj8r/1

Thank you!